# How to model pipeline processing when doing task scheduling and resource allocation in CPLEX?

Tags: scheduled-tasks, pipeline, cplex

I've come up with a task scheduling and resource allocation problem in which resources can start running a new task with a complex condition.

- A resource can start a new task on an even time unit if at least 2n time units has passed from starting the previous task started on an even time unit.
- The same holds for odd time units.

Below is a valid scheduling on a single resource. Each number represents that a new task has been started at that time.

- 0, 1, 2n, 2n+1, 4n, 4n+1, ...

I've got a lot of tasks with precedence relations in between (I know how to cope with the precedence relations) and several resources of this kind. I carried the scheduling out the following way which does not yields an optimal result:

- Although a task can start on an odd or an even time unit, I've constrained half of the tasks to start on even time units and the other half on odd time units using "forbidStart" and "stepFunction".
- Per resource s, I've considered two "cumulFunction"s s_even and s_odd.
- Tasks that are forbidden to start on even (odd) time units need the s_odd (s_even) resource. I defined this constrained using "cumulFunction" and "pulse".

Although the above procedure produces a valid scheduling, it is not enough since I'm seeking for an optimal solution. Does anybody have any idea how to carry out this problem in CPLEX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said at https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=ac7a4fa1-f304-420c-8302-18501b4b7602&ps=25 by Philippe Laborie

> just consider an additional interval variable 'task' of length 2n that represents the task and have an alternative on two optional tasks 'taskEven' and 'taskOdd'. These two intervals are the ones you already have in your model (with the adequate forbidStart constraints, and with a contribution to the adequate resource).